# Variables de javascript junto o dentro de php y viceversa

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Buenas noches hoy tengo una duda con este código que estoy probando:

```
function open_link(idurl){
var parametros = { "id" : idurl};
$.ajax({ 
data: parametros, 
url: 'control.php', 
type: 'GET',
beforeSend: function(){
}, 
success: function(response){
 console.log('<?php echo Encrypt_decrypt("decrypt", '+response+'); ?>')
instance = window.open("about:blank","_self");
instance.document.write("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url="'<?php echo Encrypt_decrypt("decrypt", '+response+'); ?>'"\">");
instance.document.close();
return false;
}});
}
```

Resulta que no me funciona como aprecian trato de capturar los datos obtenidos por `ajax` pero igual los tengo de decodificar con una función de php pero no logro entender como es la manera correcta para lograr que funcione

Gracias de ante mano y espero su ayuda

Comment: PHP es un lenguaje del lado del servidor por lo que no puedes procesar datos una vez que recibes el sitio que visualizas, por tanto, todas las funciones que utilizas en javascript debes realizarlas antes de que envies el response de `control.php` o en su defecto, encontrar su equivalente en lenguaje para javascript

Comment: si te entiendo y por eso uso ajax que funciona bien

Comment: No creo que funcione porque le estas diciendo que el tipo de dato que va a recibir es ``GET``, y eso es un ``method``, no un ``dataType``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta un ; al final de console.log().
Por otra parte, no funcionará la decodificación del response con php, ya que el codigo php es interpretado una sola vez cuando carga la página, no puedes volver a invocarla mediante algún evento como en este caso.
Te recomiendo que hagas un console.log(response), y veas en que forma llega la respuesta ya que desconozco tu control.php y como devuelve la información.

Quizas sea mejor que desde control.php simplemente devuelvas la url del sitio, y lo tomas de esta manera:

```
instance = window.open("about:blank","_self");
instance.document.write("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url="'+response+'"\">");
instance.document.close();
```

o para ser mas ordenado

```
var ventana = "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url="'+response+'"\">";
    instance = window.open("about:blank","_self");
    instance.document.write(ventana);
    instance.document.close();
```

Espero haberte ayudado. Quedo a disposición de igual manera

Comment: en efectivo la respuesta que da control.php en un echo $respuesta por lo que se puede ver la información solo con acceder a control.php?id=12345 por ejemplo. lo que yo busco es que la información sea codificada aun que sea sacada por echo